# Battery icon only displays after cable is plugged in, never before, no matter the setting

Tags: unity, icons, power-management, battery

Even when set to "always display" in the system settings or with the Ubuntu Tweak tool, the battery icon never displays until the power cable is plugged in.  Once the power cable is plugged in at least one time, the indicator "wakes up" and displays correctly (depending on setting) from then on until the laptop is rebooted.  When there is no power available when using the laptop at school, the battery icon stays invisible and I don't know how much charge is left.

indicator-power-service is running.
Resetting the dconf settings didn't help.
Restarting the service doesn't help.

Dell Inspiron 7537 laptop

Ubuntu 16.10